# either babel or webpack or my code are causing this error "Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function"

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I have a class View that I am importing and then extending it with galleryView .. Then I import the final galleryView into controller.js.. Somewhere along this path I am doing something wrong as I get this error..

`Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.. is it babel or webpack or my code?

Here's my webpack config file for development..

```
// SOURCE OF TUTORIAL
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGLUVbqoYQ&t=1205s

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: false,
  entry: {
    main: "./src/js/controller.js",
    model: "./src/js/model.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/main.html",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // injects STYLES into DOM
          "css-loader", // turns CSS into commonjs
          "sass-loader", // turns SASS into CSS
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|svg|jpe?g)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here's the View Class

```
class View {
  //   _data;
  constructor() {
    this.data;
  }

  // UPDATED for ELEMENT
  render(data) {
    if (!data) return console.log("No data!!");

    this.data = data;
    const markup = this.generateMarkup();

    this.parentElement.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", markup);
  }
}

export default new View();
```

Here's the extended galleryView

```
import View from "./view.js";

class galleryView extends View {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.parentElement = document.getElementById("gallery");
    this.errorMessage = "some error message";
    this.message = "some other message";
  }

  generateMarkup() {
    return `
     <section id="gallery" class="gallery-content"> 
<p>some text here</p>
</section>
                
    `;
  }
}

export default new galleryView();
```

Here's the opening lines for controller.js where I think the problem occurs (I could be wrong)

```
import "./../css/main.scss";
import galleryView from "./view/galleryView.js";

// GALLERY AND MORE ....
```

And here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "brahma-gallery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The frontend views for Brahma's Gallery",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js ",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "author": "Alim Bolar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
}
```

Please advise if you can figure out what I could be doing wrong.. I've googled and searched for related issues and read up some confusing stuff on babel not allowing some sort of exports etc.. but I am very new to babel and don't really know which of the related posts to follow..

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default new View();
```

should be

```
export default View;
```

or you can directly do

```
export default class View {
```

When you make a class and extend a class, you `extend` the class itself, e.g.

```
class View {}
class galleryView extends View {}
```

but right now you are incorrectly doing

```
class View {}
class galleryView extends (new View()) {}
```

where you extend an *instance* of the class, which does not make sense.

Comment: thanks @loganfsmyth .. that was really helpful.. as I am teaching myself from tutorials I tend to follow certain steps the way they were done in the tutorials .. and I guess I didn't realise this part.. but what you said makes perfect sense and thanks again for the clear explanation.. really appreciate it..:-).. As we are on this topic, I just wanted to reconfirm that what you mentioned above was for a class that I wanted to extend.. however in the case of galleryView which  I am not extending but using in controller.js, the 'new'  keyword while exporting galleryView is correct.. right?

Comment: I don't know that there is a "correct" way for your `new galleryView()` case. You'll need to use `new` somewhere, and doing it as you export is one option, but it's probably not what I would do generally because you could easily have some other type of view where you want to create two separate instances, or maybe your page has two separate galleries for some reason, in which case something somewhere would need to create two separate instances. I would favor using `new` in the file where you actually use the gallery.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and update.. I could go on and keep asking you more and more but I know that stackoverflow guidelines don't approve of too many comments..;-).. so i'll respect that for now.. and google more on this.. however if you can share some links where I could get some more info on this I'd really appreciate it.. I am basically curious to know how one could use the `new` in the file where I actually use the gallery.. the tutorial I learnt from didn't use it like that so I can't even visualise how that would be done.. I only know how to import once and use once ..;-)..